# Windows 10: Drive is not available in Explorer, but is visible on command prompt?

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 is saying 'D:\' is Currently unavailable when I click on it in Explorer.

But in command prompt (cmd.exe) and powershell I can change to D: drive and view contents with dir.

How can I fix this error in Windows 10 explorer?

Comment: It appears it might be a corruption issue that requires a Recovery or Refresh. If I figure it out, I'll answer my own question later.

Comment: What happens if you run `explorer D:` in Run or CMD?

Comment: This problem was cleaned up only by a reinstallation of Windows 10 on the affected system.

Answer (score 0):

Does D: appear correctly in Computer Management->Storage->Disk Management?  Assuming D: is a optical media drive, you get this error with and without a disk in the drive?  Is it actually a drive or had you mapped something to D: and is not longer available?  -- I cannot comment on the thread yet soooo...

Comment: It did not appear anywhere in the GUI.  Disk Management did show physical disks but not the drive letters.  A reinstallation of Windows was required to fix this. This was not the only problem on this machine.

Comment: Before you reinstalled, did you try and designate a letter in Disk Management for it?  What were the other issues?

Comment: The other issues were low level Windows stability issues. I believe that something was corrupt in this windows image.